# Turicreate iOS Image Similarity

Tags: ios, machine-learning, turi-create

I have been following the Turicreate tutorial link [here](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/blob/master/userguide/image_similarity/README.md)

I am able to train a model successfully as per instructions. I am also able to consume the model in the iOS app with the help of the code provided over there. But I am not able to figure out how could I get the most similar actual images based on the distances this model returns. Also when I run it on iPhone, it returns me offset and element which I am not able to interpret. Please see the screenshot.
[image]

My aim in the iOS application is to input an image, pass that input image to the model and then show the actual output 5 or 10 most similar images and not just the distances.

Comment: \[From [a non-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50419212/3476191) posted by [computerstaat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1530648/computerstaat)\]: "Please provide your code associated with your question. Also you should be receiving a reference label that can be used to look up your image."

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have an `id` column or have added the `id` column to your SFrame using:

```
reference_data = reference_data.add_row_number()
```

Here is a code snippet to create the `image_similarity` model and get the ten most similar images for a sample image. I use fifty as a `k` value to demonstrate that how to pull out the `n` most similar from a larger group in your similarity graph.

```
similarity_graph = model.similarity_graph(k=50)
similar_images = similarity_graph.edges
# pick a sample image from reference_data
sample_index = 3
sample_similar_images = similar_images[similar_images["__src_id"]==sample_index].sort("rank")
# get 10 most similar images
most_similar_ids = sample_similar_images["__dst_id"][0:10]
most_similar_images = reference_data.filter_by(most_similar_ids, "id")
```

For details on interpreting the distance MultiArray from the CoreML model, see the sample code in the [Turi Create documentation](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/image_similarity/export-coreml.html). The element value corresponds to the distance.